# MemberMouse [MM_Member_Link type='cancelMembership'] not working

Tags: wordpress

I have installed MemberMouse plugin on a website, to cancel a Membership, I've placed this link: 
`<a href="[MM_Member_Link type='cancelMembership']">Cancel Membership</a>`

This is the error I am getting:

[AJAX ERROR] Incorrect response data :
**Fatal error**:  Call to a member function isValid() on a non-object in **/home/sallysym/public_html/wp-content/plugins/membermouse/includes/init.php(245) : eval()'d code** on line **175**

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!
Akif

Comment: Are you trying to use a shortcode in the html?

Comment: Yes, adn this is the way it is suppose to work according to the Plugin Authors instructions.

Comment: Can you view the page source and show the rendered html?

Comment: Yes I can. Here it is: <a href="javascript:pymtutils_js.changeMembershipStatus(254, 2, 2, '');">Cancel Membership</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WordPress auth cookie is not retained when switching between HTTP and HTTPS. If the page the link is on is one, and the link itself is the other, then this one of the error messages that can be displayed.

Here's a relevant article in the WordPress forums:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/http-and-https-differences-for-function-is_user_logged_in-in-wordpress-40

In this case since the link is a JavaScript function it's ultimately handled by WordPress' admin-ajax.php. So if admin-ajax.php is being forced to the HTTPS protocol then the page you're using this SmartTag on will also have to be HTTPS in order to work.